# Laravel fullCalendar is not a function

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar

I know that there are a lot of questions about this subject here but unfortunately, I can't solve my error.

my code:

```
use  namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EventModel extends Model implements \MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Event
{
    //
    protected $dates = ['start', 'end'];
    protected $table = 'event_model';

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the event's title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Is it an all day event?
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAllDay()
    {
        return (bool)$this->all_day;
    }

    /**
     * Get the start time
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getStart()
    {
        return $this->start;
    }

    /**
     * Get the end time
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getEnd()
    {
        return $this->end;
    }
    // Implement all Event methods ...

        /**
         * Get the event's ID
         *
         * @return int|string|null
         */
}
```

my controller:

```
      $events = [];
  $events[] = $events[] = \Calendar::event(
    'Teste',
     false,
     '2017-07-10',
     '2017-07-10'
   );
  $events[] = \Calendar::event(
    'Teste2', //event title
    true, //full day event?
    new DateTime('2017-07-14'), //start time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
    new DateTime('2015-07-14') //end time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
  );

  $eloquentEvent = EventModel::first();
  $calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events)
    ->addEvent($eloquentEvent, ['color' => '#800',
    ])->setOptions([
      'firstDay' => 1
    ])->setCallbacks(['viewRender' => 'function() {alert("Callbacks");}'
  ]);
  return view('my view', compact('calendar'))
```

my view:

```
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css"/> 
//...//
{!! $calendar->calendar() !!}
{!! $calendar->script() !!}
```

My error:

```
> 3:259 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (3:259)
    at j (jquery.js:3094)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3206)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3412)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.js:3428)
```

I think my error happens because of the script but I have the same calendar in other controller with the same libs and it works fine, the difference is that this controller and this view have more code but I think that it is not a problem.

I need help.

Comment: Try `$(document).ready(function() {` before your javascript code and post your javascript code aswell if that does not work

Comment: what does the rendered view look like? (i.e. page source in the browser)? And why such an old version of fullCalendar? 3.4 is the most recent and will have a lot of extra features and bugfixes.

Comment: @ADyson i my view does not appear anything about the calendar, i just know the error because of the function 'inspect' of the chrome

Comment: on the face of it the error makes it looks like the fullCalendar library is either not included in your page, or is not included before a call to the .fullCalendar function is made. That's why I want to see the rendered view - just some Laravel code doesn't show us how the page actually ends up being generated, and that's the important thing. The page won't show the calendar because the error you're getting prevents it. That doesn't mean there isn't some script in there to try and create the calendar. So please do View Source on your generated page and post it here, so we can analyse it.